# Problems with ssh connection

Tags: debian, ssh

I was trying to connect to my raspberry in local network by ssh from my pc where I have debian os.
I tried to connect typing `ssh pi@IP_ADDRESS` and this return me after a while

`connect to host IP_ADDRESS port 22: Connection timed out`

Insted typing `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` I have managed to connect to the device. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `raspberrypi.local` maps to a different IP address than `93.36.114.204`. If you got that address from a separate document it's possible they just listed whatever IP address it resolved to on their system. You can try `getent hosts raspberrypi.local` or `gethostip raspberrypi.local` to [see which address it actually maps to](https://superuser.com/questions/305939/bash-lookup-an-ip-for-a-host-name-including-etc-hosts-in-search).